# How to clean up other resources when spark gets stopped

Tags: scala, apache-spark, akka

In my spark application, there is an `object ResourceFactory` which contains an akka `ActorSystem` for providing resource clients. So when I run this spark application, every worker node will create an `ActorSystem`. The problem is that when the spark application finishes its works and gets shutdown. The `ActorSystem` still keeps alive on every worker node and prevents the whole application to terminate, it's just hung on.

Is there a way to register some listener to the `SparkContext` so that when the `sc` gets shutdown, then the `ActorSystem` on every worker node will get notified to shutdown themselves?

---

UPDATE:

Following is the simplified skeleton:

There is a `ResourceFactory`, which is an `object` and it contains an `actor system`. And it also provides a `fetchData` method.

```
object ResourceFactory{
  val actorSystem = ActorSystem("resource-akka-system")
  def fetchData(): SomeData = ...
}
```

And then, there is a `user-defined RDD` class, in its `compute` method, it needs to fetch data from the `ResourceFactory`.

```
class MyRDD extends RDD[SomeClass] {
  override def compute(...) {
    ...
    ResourceFactory.fetchData()
    ...
    someIterator
  }
}
```

So on every node there will be one `ActorSystem` named "resource-akka-system", and those `MyRDD` instances distributed on those worker nodes can get data from the "resource-akka-system".

The problem is that, when the `SparkContext` gets shutdown, there is no need for those "resource-akka-system"s, but I don't know how to notify the `ResourceFactory` to shutdown the "resource-akka-system" when the `SparkContext` gets shutdown. So now, the "resouce-akka-system" keeps alive on each worker node and prevents the whole program to exit.

---

UPDATE2:

With some more experiments, I find that in local mode the program is hung on, but in `yarn-cluster` mode, the program will exit successfully. May be this is because `yarn` will kill the threads on worker nodes when the `sc` is shutdown?

---

UPDATE3:

To check whether every node contains an `ActorSystem`, I change the code as following(following is the real skeleton, as I add another class definition):

```
object ResourceFactory{
  println("creating resource factory")
  val actorSystem = ActorSystem("resource-akka-system")
  def fetchData(): SomeData = ...
}

class MyRDD extends RDD[SomeClass] {
  println("creating my rdd")
  override def compute(...) {
    new RDDIterator(...)
  }
}

class RDDIterator(...) extends Iterator[SomeClass] {
  println("creating rdd iterator")
  ...
  lazy val reader = {
    ...
    ResourceFactory.fetchData()
    ...
  }
  ...
  override next() = {
    ...
    reader.xx()
  }
}
```

After adding those `println`s, I run the code on spark on yarn-cluster mode. I find that on the driver I have following prints:

```
creating my rdd
creating resource factory
creating my rdd
...
```

While on some of the workers, I have following prints:

```
creating rdd iterator
creating resource factory
```

And some of the workers, it prints nothing (and all of them are not assigned any tasks).

Based on the above, I think the `object` is initialized in driver eagerly, since it prints `creating resource factory` on the driver even when no thing refers to it, and `object` is initialized in worker lazily because it prints `creating resource factory` after printing `creating rdd iterator` as resource factory is lazily referenced by the first created RDDIterator.

And I find that in my use case the `MyRDD` class is only created in the driver.

I am not very sure about the laziness of the initialization of the `object` on driver and worker, it's my guess, because maybe it's caused by other part of the program to make it looks like that. But I think it should be right that there is one actor system on each worker node when it is necessary.

Comment: The weird thing is why you would need an actor system on spark node, given spark is already running on top of Akka.

Comment: @zinking spark1.6 doesn't use akka, and I'm doing some work based on a 3rd party lib. Even if spark is running on top of akka, I think writing my lib sharing the akka used in spark is not a good idea, too much coupled.

Comment: @宇宙人 Actually 1.6 is still using Akka for RPC calls. It has been replaced in 2.0.

Comment: @宇宙人 I'm not suggesting to use existing akka system, I mean what is the stuff that you have to use akka, while spark can't achieve it? if such a thing does exist why you choose spark in the first place.

Comment: @zero323 oh, yeah, you are right. I mistook the current master branch of spark as the branch-1.6.

Comment: @zinking I'm doing some work based on a 3rd party lib. That lib uses a local akka system on each worker node to serve as a resource pool. Of course that functionality can be achieved without akka. But to rewrite that part requires much efforts. And spark is used to do other things. I dont understand why it's weird to use both of them, I think they are different approaches. Back to the original question's title, I imagine that there may exist some situation where we need to start sth on worker  as worker start to run and stop it when worker finishes its job.(of course that may be

Comment: @zinking worked around in other way, but that may be less efficiency or sth else.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that there is a way to tap into each `Worker` lifecycle.

Also I have some questions regarding your implementation:

1. If you have `object` that contains `val`, that is used from function run on worker, my understanding is that this `val` gets serialized and broadcasted to worker. Can you confirm, that you have one ActorSystem running per worker?
2. Actor System usually terminated immediately if you don't explicitly wait for it's termination. Are you calling something like `system.awaitTermination` or blocking on `system.whenTerminated`?

Anyway, there is another way, how you can shutdown actor systems on remote workers:

1. Make your ActorSystem on each node part of the akka cluster. [Here are some docs](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/java/remoting.html#Programmatic_Remote_Deployment) how to do that programmatically.
2. Have address of your "coordination" Actor on driver node (where your `sc` is) broadcasted to each worker. In simple words, just have `val` with that address.
3. When your akka system is started on each worker use that "coordination" Actor address to register this particular actor system (send corresponding message to coordination Actor).
4. Coordination Actor keeps track of all registered "worker" Actors
5. When your computation is completed and you want to shut down Akka system on every worker, send messages to all registered Actors from coordination Actor on driver node.
6. Shutdown on worker Akka systems when "shutdown" message is received.

Comment: For the first question, I need days later to confirm every  worker node has an ActorSystem. Now theoretically speaking, I think that when starting the spark, all the bytecode will be shipped to every machine, so when I refer to an object in the code of RDD, it will refer to the local shipped and classloaded object instance. Based on that I think every node has one ActorSystem. If it's wrong, then I think I misunderstand spark very much, and plz point out and correct me.

Comment: For the second question, plz see the update2 in the question, which I think it's related. Back to the question, I don't call anything like `system.awitTermination`. And I think Actor System will not terminate unless I call something like `system.shutdown`. Maybe I am wrong again.

Comment: @宇宙人, according to Programming Guide, your code is shipped to driver node, which then distributes bytecode along with serialized "closed scope" to the workers. Check the [Passing Function to Spark](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#passing-functions-to-spark) section. But I'm not 100% sure what happens in your case with Actor System, so it worth checking.

Comment: @宇宙人, regarding actor system termination, I [created a simple test](https://gist.github.com/Aivean/2c966f47cf119ddb2085fe9f43b5ee7a), that terminates immediately. Both messages are correctly handled. I presume whether akka system terminates immediately may be dependent on dispatcher configuration, specifically, whether underlying thread pool keeps non-daemon threads alive. So, this is worth checking too.

Comment: The spark programming guide is talking about referencing things that are initialized in driver program. I doubt it's different in my case as the object instance is referenced inside RDD implementation. I will check both questions after this weekend. I will update the question with some experiment results next week. Thanks again for your quick response.

Comment: @Aivean Can you include some practical examples?

Comment: @Aivean I've update the question to include the test on the existence of actor system on workers. I think it's different from referencing things that are initialized in driver as described in the spark programming guide.

Comment: @Aivean I tried your test code on the termination of actor system. But if you run your code in the main method not in the test environment, it will not terminate automatically, [link](https://gist.github.com/wuciawe/01a09a1010b811b1a7b07928ca7e7861). I also try to embed the code into a daemon as [link](https://gist.github.com/wuciawe/17322f04074971575ed3670d40559413), it terminates without doing anything.  How can the test suite know the actor system right finishes all the jobs.

Comment: @宇宙人, you are right, I missed that main context behaves differently. And frankly, I don't understand why. However, if you make akka use daemonic threads, it will live only while your main thread is alive. Check out [this test](https://gist.github.com/Aivean/c96a7157dfd94e7b1f7415169496b8da). I suppose you're using some kind on blocking call in `fetchData`? If yes, this approach may work for you.

Comment: @Aivean Does `I don't understand why` refer to that you tried the first link in my last reply and the program also hangs on, and you don't know why it hangs? Or do you mean you don't understand why `scala-test suite` knows when actor system finishes all the jobs.

Comment: @宇宙人, it hangs in main context for me too, and I don't know why behavior in test context is different.

Comment: @Aivean how to control akka use daemon or non-daemon threads?

Comment: @宇宙人, check the gist in my comment above. You need to specify       `akka { daemonic = on ... }` in akka configuration, or use custom dispatcher with overridden thread factory.

Comment: @Aivean Thank you very much for all those replies. It helps me know so many new stuffs.